# Can't use any environment variable

Tags: node.js, windows, git, environment-variables

Firstly, I just got a restored PC (Windows 7) in my company, so I don't exactly know what has been done to it.

Here is my problem: I installed nodejs, but I couldn't use the command "node" in the command prompt. I thought it was linked to the envionment variables path, so I went to the settings, checked the system variable "PATH", and saw that ";C:\Program Files\nodejs\" was already here.

From here, I tried many things:

- Creating a user variable "path" (which is supposed to override the system one, right?)
- Change nodejs path from ";C:\Program Files\nodejs\" to ";C:\Program Files\nodejs"
- I'm logged in as administrator, so I also checked the users' environment variables, everything looked ok
- I tried installing nodejs in another directory, not protected (such as "My documents"), and then modified the path according to
- I tried installing other versions of nodejs (older versions, 32/64 bits versions, etc...)
- Of course, I did reboot the command prompt and my PC
- EDIT: Here's the output when I type PATH in the cmd prompt: [image: PATH command output]
- I noticed that I could use the "node" and "npm" commands if the command prompt was located in the installation folder

[image: I can use the command in the installation folder and only there]

- Finally, I started thinking it was not linked to nodejs. I tried to use the git commands, and the same thing happened : all the commands are unknown excepted in the installation folder (the path seems to be correct too).

I think now that my issue is linked to the system and more specifically to the environment variables, not to any software.

I'm now running out of ideas that's why I'm asking for yours...
Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What does `dir node.*` in that installation folder show you?

Comment: Type `PATH` in the command window, copy and paste the output into your question.

Comment: - I edited my post and added the output of the PATH command.

- When I type "dir node.*" I get the path "C:\Program Files\nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: after reviewing your PATH it's clear it's Invalid.

Remove the " after GnuWin32

Then save the PATH and open a new prompt.   You should be good to go!

---

Try the following troubleshooting steps in order.

### Invalid character(s) in PATH

#### Extra whitespace

Incorrect

```
    "C:\Windows; C:\Program Files\git;C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

Correct

```
    "C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\git;C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

---

#### PATH contains illegal character

Incorrect

```
    "C:\Windows";C:\Program Files\git;C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

Correct

```
    "C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\git;C:\Program Files\nodejs"
```

Comment: There's no problem with a PATH that starts with an environment variable; in fact, that's true in the default configuration.  Also `regedit.exe` and `regedt32.exe` are the same application, have been for ages - are you perhaps using a VERY old version of Windows?

Comment: Thanks for identifying this. It appears this document by Microsoft is outdated, as it was last reviewed in 2008. I've removed the section on expanding environment variables.